Display invisible characters
What is the setting to hide invisible characters, but to display invisible characters in visual mode?
I like to hide characters as TAB (visible-mode off).
However, when highlighting text to yank, it would be nice to see these invisible characters in the highlighted line. Is this possible?
I am using evil-mode.

What do invisible characters have to do with evil?  Do you mean visible-mode rather than visual-mode?  Do you mean any character hidden by text properties, or are you talking about "zero-width" unicode characters?  Please clarify your question (preferably with examples).

Are you by any chance looking for whitespace-mode?

The question is unclear. Specify what you mean by invisible characters, etc. Emacs has different ways of making text invisible.

Based on your edits, the "simplest" hack I can think of is to make an alternative font which is a copy of your regular font, but with the "invisible" characters rendered in the way you want.  Then assign that font to the region face in Emacs.  It's a brute-force approach, but should be pretty effective.
